# prevent some user from seeing db2 tables structure

Tags: database, security, db2

How can I restrict some users in DB2, not to see the table structure. I set the user privilege and restrict user from table access. so that user can not select data or change table but still can see the table structure or describe it.

Comment: were you able to get solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I think that would be possible in db210+.
I did not work on that as I wanted to do that on db2 9.7 luw. It refers to row access in tables which is added in db2 version 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem refers to row access in tables which is added in db2 version 10.

I had this problem too.

you can use this version - if applicable- and restrict user access from specific table structures.

Comment: Okay, _how_ do you restrict access to specific table structures.  What steps are you taking?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the select grant on catalog tables. For example, the following query should return 0 rows when executing with q restricted user.

```
db2 "select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables"
```

All tables and views in the following schemas should not have select on public, nor in any group the restrictive user is in.

- sysibm
- syscat

Comment: Thank you, but I want to make this restriction customize, for example I want user A could see the table A, however could not see the table B structure and data.

Comment: You want to allow to see part of the database structure. It means, you want to hide some rows, and that is LBAC, but I am not sure if you can use it on catalog tables: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0021114.html

Answer (score -1):

```
db2 revoke select on SYSIBM.SYSTABLES from username
```